# Is there any way to automate the publication of application to mac Store?

Tags: macos, deployment, automation

I am looking for a way I can automate the process of uploading a new iPhone application version to mac Store. 
Do you know how could I do this?

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 0):

Just to help someone who needs something similar. I did some approach using selenium and Automator.
I used selenium + python to automate the web part, then I used Automator to Archive and submit the application to the Store.
Currently I am still working on this problem.